# Shortest way to get an Iterator over a range of Integers in Java

Tags: java, iterator

What's the shortest way to get an Iterator over a range of Integers in Java? In other words, implement the following:

```
/** 
* Returns an Iterator over the integers from first to first+count.
*/
Iterator<Integer> iterator(Integer first, Integer count);
```

Something like

```
(first..first+count).iterator()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just "add 1", in the classic fashion? Just of interest

Comment: It's a framework that requires me to write an iterator

Comment: Clarity trumps breviety everytime and there are a numerous Range classes available out that include iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight-forward implementation of your homework:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ints.add(first + i);
}
```

Comment: That's the right one if you take "shortest" seriously, except that you're missing "return ints.iterator();" ;-)

Comment: Also, it's memory inneficient.

Comment: I think it's a bit condescending to call this homework. This is a very frequent usecase, and as seen below there are better implementations then this (albeit not all of them were possible at the time of writing).

Answer (score 80):

This implementation does not have a memory footprint.

```
/**
 * @param begin inclusive
 * @param end exclusive
 * @return list of integers from begin to end
 */
public static List<Integer> range(final int begin, final int end) {
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer get(int index) {
                return begin + index;
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return end - begin;
            }
        };
}
```

### Edit:

In Java 8 and later you can simply say:

```
IntStream.range(begin, end).iterator()          // returns PrimitiveIterator.OfInt
```

or if you need the boxed version:

```
IntStream.range(begin, end).boxed().iterator()  // returns Iterator<Integer>
```

Comment: While the listing itself is quite short it returns a List instead of an Iterable / Iterator which offers many more interface methods. These are not implemented here and this in turn might lead to unexpected results if the list instance is used in "unforeseen" context. So you could say this implementation breaks the List interface contract.
Also, the implementation of the iterator in AbstractList is not as simple as it could be and uses more instance variables than necessary, so there is some small memory footprint.
I'd therefore rather go for a direct implementation of Iterable / Iterator.

Comment: @DanielBimschas I think that's not true. This class does adhere to the contract of an _unmodifiable_ list, as defined in the JavaDoc for [`java.util.Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). In particular, it throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if someone calls one of it's "destructive" methods like `add()` or `remove()`.

For more details also see the JavaDoc of [`java.util.AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html).

Comment: @Saintali fair point w.r.t. my "breaks the List interface contract" comment. Please ignore this part. IMHO my other comments remain valid though.

Comment: The `get()` method should check if its parameter is in the valid range, and if not (e.g. negative or larger than size) throw `IndexOutofBoundsException`.

Comment: Getting nitpicky. The list *does* have a memory footprint (`begin` and `end`) but it is constant.

Answer (score 17):

Untested. Mapping that onto "min, count" is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
public class IntRangeIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
  private int nextValue;
  private final int max;
  public IntRangeIterator(int min, int max) {
    if (min > max) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("min must be <= max");
    }
    this.nextValue = min;
    this.max = max;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
    return nextValue <= max;
  }

  public Integer next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    return Integer.valueOf(nextValue++);
  }

  public void remove() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

Comment: this looks almost identical to the one I just wrote for myself :)

Answer (score 9):

If you actually want the shortest amount of code, then Bombe's answer is fine. However, it sucks memory for no good reason. If you want to implement it yourself, it would be something like:

```
import java.util.*;

public class IntegerRange implements Iterator<Integer>
{
    private final int start;
    private final int count;

    private int position = -1;

    public IntegerRange(int start, int count)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return position+1 < count;
    }

    public Integer next()
    {
        if (position+1 >= count)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        position++;
        return start + position;
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An example using the guava framework.  Note that this will not materialize the set (although you have to read the ContiguousSet implementation to verify that).

```
import com.google.common.collect.ContiguousSet;
import com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomain;
import com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomains;

class RangeIterator { 

    public Iterator<Integer> range(int start, int length) {
        assert length > 0;
        Range<Integer> dim_range = Ranges.closedOpen(start, start + length);
        DiscreteDomain<Integer> ints = DiscreteDomains.integers();
        ContiguousSet<Integer> dim = dim_range.asSet(ints);
        return dim.iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: the shortest version of this one: `Iterator<Integer> range = Ranges.closedOpen(start, end).asSet(DiscreteDomains.integers()).iterator();`

Comment: @Miguel The `Range#asSet(DiscreteDomain)` method [is deprecated and has been removed in Guava 16](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html#asSet(com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomain)).

Comment: @Synoli `Iterator<Integer> range = ContiguousSet.create(Ranges.closedOpen(start, end), DiscreteDomains.integers()).iterator();`

Answer (score 7):

A sample using stream API in java 8:

```
int first = 0;
int count = 10;
Iterator<Integer> it = IntStream.range(first, first + count).iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Without iterator, it could be:

```
int first = 0;
int count = 10;
IntStream.range(first, first + count).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered good style to pass around `Collection` and friends instead of `Iterator` (see [this FAQ entry](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/collections/designfaq.html#8)), so I'd recommend something like

```
public final class IntegerRange implements Set<Integer> {
        final LinkedHashSet<Integer> backingList;
        public IntegerRange(final int start, final int count) {
                backingList = new LinkedHashSet(count, 1.0f);
                for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
                        backingList.set(i, start + i);
                }       
        }       
        /** Insert a bunch of delegation methods here */
}
```

and then just use `.iterator()` when you need to pass an `Iterator` to whatever framework you're using.

UPDATE: Obviously, this code isn't lazy. If you can't afford the extra memory overhead of storing (potentially) 2^32-1 `Integer`s, you should use a different solution. Also, nothing about the type guarantees the range will be sorted (even though it is, based on the implementation). If you need to guarantee sorting, you could look into implementing [SortedSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) and backing it with a [TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), but it will take longer to build the range. Honestly, if you are that concerned with getting the details right, it might be worth your effort to look for a library. Tapestry has an [internal version](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/internal/util/IntegerRange.html), for instance.

Comment: Why implement that in a backing set? It's rather easy to implement that without storing all Integers (which can be rather memory intensive), as long as you don't need to support add() and remove(). I'd also add that a List would be more fitting (as there's definitely some order)

Comment: RE: List -> cretzel didn't specify a ListIterator, and Iterator makes no ordering guarantees, so I went with the closest mapping (Collection), though in retrospect, I would have used Set.
RE: lazy -> that seemed like a lot more work, plus cretzel made no mention of not needing remove() support.

Comment: The FAQ entry you are referring to tells us that we should not pass Iterators around a collection of objects. But if you are interested not in the collection but in the iteration process, passing an Iterator is quite OK.

Comment: I think Collection vs. Iterator really depends. The guys at Google seem to favor Iterator for their applications:  see "Why so much emphasis on Iterators and Iterables?" here: http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/wiki/Faq