# For loop - like Python range function

Tags: java, function, for-loop

I was wondering if in Java there is a function like the python range function.

```
range(4)
```

and it would return

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

This was an easy way to make for enhanced loops. It would be great to do this in Java because it would make for loops a lot easier. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to write it yourself? It's not that hard

Comment: Some nice solutions are also in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371026/shortest-way-to-get-an-iterator-over-a-range-of-integers-in-java

Comment: For a range of any `Comparable` s see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245738/3992939) answer

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Java 8 (2014) has added [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) (similar to apache commons IntRange), so you don't need external lib now.

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream; 

IntStream.range(0, 3).forEachOrdered(n -> {
    System.out.println(n);
});
```

`forEach` can be used in place of `forEachOrdered` too if order is not important.

`IntStream.range(0, 3).parallel()` can be used for loops to run in parallel

Comment: Nice, but puts limitations on variables used in the lambda expression so might not be handy.

Answer (score 24):

Without an external library, you can do the following. It will consume significantly less memory for big ranges than the current accepted answer, as there is no array created.

Have a class like this:

```
class Range implements Iterable<Integer> {

    private int limit;

    public Range(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        final int max = limit;
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {

            private int current = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return current < max;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    return current++;   
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException("Range reached the end");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can't remove values from a Range");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and you can simply use it like this:

```
    for (int i : new Range(5)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

you can even reuse it:

```
    Range range5 = new Range(5);

    for (int i : range5) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    for (int i : range5) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

---

As [Henry Keiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069350/henry-keiter) pointed out in the comment below, we could add following method to the `Range` class (or anywhere else):

```
public static Range range(int max) {
    return new Range(max);
}
```

and then, in the other classes we can

```
import static package.name.Range.range;
```

and simply call

```
for (int i : range(5)) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually writing out an Iterator for this! For fun: you could further wrap this in Python-like syntax with a simple getter method: `public static Range range(int max) { return new Range(max); }`, so your loop becomes `for (int i : range(5)) {}`

Comment: @HenryKeiter That's a nice suggestion, I like it so much I'll update my answer (and give you the credit).

Comment: It is a nice answer, but not to the question. It simply implies that 'No, there is not a function like range, you must implement your own iterator'. Sorry, -1 for that.

Answer (score 15):

Um... `for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)`? You don't have to write enhanced for loops all day, you know, although they are cool...

And just for the sake of argument:

`for (int i : range(k))`  char count: 22

`for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)` char count: 27

Discounting the implementation of `range`, it is pseudo even.

Comment: Well this is the normal way to do it, but it would be a lot simpler if you could make an array for the loop to use.

Comment: This isn't what he's asking, though; he wants to know if there's an "easier" way.

Comment: @HenryKeiter:that's true, just trying to counter OP's argument: "It would be great to do this in java because it would makes for loops a lot easier".

Comment: Well, I certainly can't disagree with you there. Seems like a lot of effort just to save a couple of characters (and ignore all conventions on the way), but I'm not here to judge what (anti-)idioms people might want to use :)

Comment: @ExotickBoyPl you can make somethink _like_ an array, just much more efficient, if you look at my answer ;)

Comment: Just to be clear, range() is not a Java function, in case any idiots like me want to try it. :P

Answer (score 11):

Use [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html#toArray()):

```
new IntRange(0, 3).toArray();
```

I wouldn't normally advocate introducing external libraries for something so simple, but Apache Commons are so widely used that you probably already have it in your project!

Edit: I know its not necessarily as simple or fast as a for loop, but its a nice bit of syntactic sugar that makes the intent clear.

Edit: See @zengr's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31867991/231917) using `IntStream` in Java 8 .

Comment: Well its not ,but I was expecting it to be, its still go to know

Comment: This will also be much slower than the traditional for loop.

Comment: This solution is pretty inefficient - you need a big array for big ranges. [Extending AbstractList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371026/shortest-way-to-get-an-iterator-over-a-range-of-integers-in-java#answer-6828887) is the simplest efficient solution I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really want to obtain an equivalent result in Java, you'll have to do some more work:

```
public int[] range(int start, int end, int step) {
    int n = (int) Math.ceil((end-start)/(double)step);
    int[] arange = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arange[i] = i*step+start;
    return arange;
}
```

Now `range(0, 4, 1)` will return the expected value, just like Python: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Sadly there isn't a simpler way in Java, it's *not* a very expressive language, like Python.

Comment: The implementation has some flaws. Run `int[] range = range(5, 33, 5); System.out.println(Arrays.toString(range));`

Answer (score 2):

Its not available that true. But you make a static method and use it -

```
public static int[] range(int index){
    int[] arr = new int[index];
    for(int i=0;i<index;i++){
        arr[i]=i;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: That will create a **huge** array, if you want a range to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ;)

Comment: You could just check you available primary memory, even you may add some more heheh :P

Answer (score 0):

There's no Java equivalent to the `range` function, but there is an [enhanced for-loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with):

```
for (String s : strings) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

You could also roll your own `range` function, if you're really attached to the syntax, but it seems a little silly.

```
public static int[] range(int length) {
    int[] r = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        r[i] = i;
    }
    return r;
}

// ...

String s;
for (int i : range(arrayOfStrings.length)) {
    s = arrayOfStrings[i];
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: That will create a **huge** array, if you want a range to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ;)

Comment: @jlordo Well that's certainly true ;-) But the same is true of the `range` function in Python (2), and I felt like writing up an Iterator was overkill for just trying to avoid writing a basic loop (+1 to your answer for actually doing it though, lol).

Comment: certainly overkill for a simple loop. Although you could modify the iterator to use all of the other options the Python `range()` method has and use much less memory ;) Thanks for +1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's not an equivalent function in java. But you can write it yourself:

```
public static int[] range(int n) {
    int[] ans = new int[n];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ans[i] = i;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: That will create a **huge** array, if you want a range to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ;)

Comment: @jlordo If you push it to that, yes, it will... and so would python's `range()` function

Comment: that's why I like Java, because it is easy to have the functionality without using that much memory :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to substitute the range in python in java can be done with the following code. NOTE: I am not going off of your code, I am just writing a small piece of code and showing it to you.

in python you would do.. . .

```
if -2 <= x <= 10:
     print(x)
```

in java you would substitute this range and do. . ..

```
if(x >= -2 && x <= 10){
System.out.println("x")
}
```

By doing the above code in java, you don't need a range, but you have the
-2 <= x <=10 range and split it into x >= -2 and x <= 10. It means the same thing, but the one I explained in java may take the compiler a longer time to read. So if you are using python go with the former's code format, and if you are using java, use the latter's code format.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and congratulations on your first answer. Here we try to keep answers focused on the specific question asked -- it is not immediately clear how what you wrote relates to the specific question of whether there was an equivalent of `range(,,)` in Java. You may want to enhance your answer by linking it more directly to the specific question